# Is there a way to optimize a group by median query?

Tags: mysql, group-by, median

I wrote a query that finds the median of values for each month. Doing this was difficult enough because MySQL doesn't have a built in median function so I really had to think outside the box with my intermediate SQL skills. But now the problem is that it takes really long (1 or 2 mins sometimes) to run the query. Is there a way to optimize this query? Or perhaps I should write a python script that finds the median and pushes it to the database using a connector?

Here is the query:

```
SET @row_num_pos := 0;
SET @median_group_pos := '';
SET @row_num_neg := 0;
SET @median_group_neg := '';

SELECT 
    p.month_num AS 'month_num',
    CASE
        WHEN p.month_num = 1 THEN 'Jan'
        WHEN p.month_num = 2 THEN 'Feb'
        WHEN p.month_num = 3 THEN 'Mar'
        WHEN p.month_num = 4 THEN 'Apr'
        WHEN p.month_num = 5 THEN 'May'
        WHEN p.month_num = 6 THEN 'Jun'
        WHEN p.month_num = 7 THEN 'Jul'
        WHEN p.month_num = 8 THEN 'Aug'
        WHEN p.month_num = 9 THEN 'Sep'
        WHEN p.month_num = 10 THEN 'Oct'
        WHEN p.month_num = 11 THEN 'Nov'
        WHEN p.month_num = 12 THEN 'Dec'
    END AS 'Timeline',
    p.ck_pos_median AS 'CK+ Median',
    n.ck_neg_median AS 'CK- Median'
FROM
    (SELECT 
        s.median_month_pos AS 'month_num',
            ROUND(AVG(ck_pos), 1) AS 'ck_pos_median'
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        @row_num_pos:=CASE
                WHEN @median_group_pos = q.month_num THEN @row_num_pos + 1
                ELSE 1
            END AS 'count_of_group',
            @median_group_pos:=q.month_num AS 'median_month_pos',
            q.month_num,
            q.ck_pos,
            (SELECT 
                    COUNT(*)
                FROM
                    Biocept_DB.result_management_report
                WHERE
                    ck_pos IS NOT NULL
                        AND MONTH(order_date) = q.month_num) AS total_month
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        MONTH(order_date) AS 'month_num', ck_pos
    FROM
        Biocept_DB.result_management_report
    WHERE
        ck_pos IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY MONTH(order_date) , ck_pos ASC) AS q) AS s
    WHERE
        s.count_of_group BETWEEN (s.total_month / 2.0) AND (s.total_month / 2.0 + 1)
    GROUP BY s.median_month_pos) AS p
        JOIN
    (SELECT 
        s.median_month_neg AS 'month_num',
            ROUND(AVG(ck_neg), 1) AS 'ck_neg_median'
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        @row_num_neg:=CASE
                WHEN @median_group_neg = q.month_num THEN @row_num_neg + 1
                ELSE 1
            END AS 'count_of_group',
            @median_group_neg:=q.month_num AS 'median_month_neg',
            q.month_num,
            q.ck_neg,
            (SELECT 
                    COUNT(*)
                FROM
                    Biocept_DB.result_management_report
                WHERE
                    ck_neg IS NOT NULL
                        AND MONTH(order_date) = q.month_num) AS total_month
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        MONTH(order_date) AS 'month_num', ck_neg
    FROM
        Biocept_DB.result_management_report
    WHERE
        ck_neg IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY MONTH(order_date) , ck_neg ASC) AS q) AS s
    WHERE
        s.count_of_group BETWEEN (s.total_month / 2.0) AND (s.total_month / 2.0 + 1)
    GROUP BY s.median_month_neg) AS n ON p.month_num = n.month_num
ORDER BY p.month_num;

SET @row_num_pos := NULL;
SET @median_group_pos := NULL;
SET @row_num_neg := NULL;
SET @median_group_neg := NULL;
```

Here is the table it generates:
[image]

Comment: in MariaDB is a MEDIAN Function see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/median/ . i am not sure this also in MySQL implementet

Comment: There is not a MEDIAN function in MySQL. Because of this I've been thinking of transitioning for a while.

Comment: do you have some raw data and create table definition for me to test (pastebin)

Comment: is possible to get Data from you. I am nearly sure that i can optimize it

Comment: Sure I will export and send to you both.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/AqJX8iRX here it is @BerndBuffen

Comment: can you me also send the create statement of your table

Comment: is it not easyer to send the create table and th sql dump ?

Comment: I am not sure why but I cannot use mysqldump. Maybe because the database is hosted onto a AWS server and not locally? Here's the create statement for the table without anydata. Could you just create a simple table and upload the data pasted? Result_management_report_id is PK, order_date is date, and ck_pos and ck_neg are int(11) with default null.

I apologize for not being of much help. I tried mysqldump

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your query a little bit. I hope that the calculation is correct. With you sample date the results are the same.

I my environment your query take 6.22 seconds and my only 20 ms. so it looks 300 times faster.

please test my query and let me know if it works for you. is the speed not good we can optimize a little more with virtual columns.

Please don't forget to set **group_concat_max_len** to a good value for you.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

**Query**

```
SELECT  r.Timeline AS `month_number`
        , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( 'Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec', ',' , r.Timeline ) , ',' , -1)
            AS Timeline
        , ( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.grp_ck_pos, ',' , (r.cnt_ck_pos>>1)+1 ) , ',' , -1) +
            SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.grp_ck_pos, ',' , (r.cnt_ck_pos>>1) + 1 - ((r.cnt_ck_pos&1) XOR 1) ) , ',' , -1) 
            ) / 2 AS 'ck_pos_median'
        , ( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.grp_ck_neg, ',' , (r.cnt_ck_neg>>1)+1 ) , ',' , -1) +
            SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.grp_ck_neg, ',' , (r.cnt_ck_neg>>1) + 1 - ((r.cnt_ck_neg&1) XOR 1) ) , ',' , -1) 
            ) / 2 AS 'ck_neg_median'
FROM (
        SELECT  MONTH(`order_date`) AS 'Timeline'
            , SUM(IF(ck_pos is NULL,0,1)) AS cnt_ck_pos
            , GROUP_CONCAT(ck_pos ORDER BY ck_pos) as grp_ck_pos
            , SUM(IF(ck_neg is NULL,0,1)) AS cnt_ck_neg
            , GROUP_CONCAT(ck_neg ORDER BY ck_neg) as grp_ck_neg
        FROM result_management_report
        where (ck_pos is not null or ck_neg is not null) = 1
        GROUP BY Timeline
) r;
```

**Table definition**

**Sample new query**

```
mysql> SELECT r.Timeline AS `month_number`
    -> , SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( 'Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec', ',' , r.Timeline ) , ',' , -1)
    -> AS Timeline
    -> , ( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.grp_ck_pos, ',' , (r.cnt_ck_pos>>1)+1 ) , ',' , -1) +
    -> SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.grp_ck_pos, ',' , (r.cnt_ck_pos>>1) + 1 - ((r.cnt_ck_pos&1) XOR 1) ) , ',' , -1) 
    -> ) / 2 AS 'ck_pos_median'
    -> , ( SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.grp_ck_neg, ',' , (r.cnt_ck_neg>>1)+1 ) , ',' , -1) +
    -> SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.grp_ck_neg, ',' , (r.cnt_ck_neg>>1) + 1 - ((r.cnt_ck_neg&1) XOR 1) ) , ',' , -1) 
    -> ) / 2 AS 'ck_neg_median'
    -> FROM (
    -> SELECT MONTH(`order_date`) AS 'Timeline'
    -> , SUM(IF(ck_pos is NULL,0,1)) AS cnt_ck_pos
    -> , GROUP_CONCAT(ck_pos ORDER BY ck_pos) as grp_ck_pos
    -> , SUM(IF(ck_neg is NULL,0,1)) AS cnt_ck_neg
    -> , GROUP_CONCAT(ck_neg ORDER BY ck_neg) as grp_ck_neg
    -> FROM result_management_report
    -> where (ck_pos is not null or ck_neg is not null) = 1
    -> GROUP BY Timeline
    -> ) r;
+--------------+----------+---------------+---------------+
| month_number | Timeline | ck_pos_median | ck_neg_median |
+--------------+----------+---------------+---------------+
|            1 | Jan      |             2 |             2 |
|            2 | Feb      |             2 |             3 |
|            3 | Mar      |             2 |             3 |
|            4 | Apr      |             4 |             4 |
|            5 | May      |             2 |             3 |
|            6 | Jun      |             3 |             3 |
|            7 | Jul      |             4 |             4 |
|            8 | Aug      |             3 |             7 |
|            9 | Sep      |             4 |            12 |
|           10 | Oct      |             5 |             8 |
|           11 | Nov      |             4 |             9 |
|           12 | Dec      |             2 |            12 |
+--------------+----------+---------------+---------------+
12 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

**Sample old query**

```
mysql> 
mysql> SET @row_num_pos := 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @median_group_pos := '';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @row_num_neg := 0;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @median_group_neg := '';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> SELECT 
    ->     p.month_num AS 'month_num',
    ->     CASE
    ->         WHEN p.month_num = 1 THEN 'Jan'
    ->         WHEN p.month_num = 2 THEN 'Feb'
    ->         WHEN p.month_num = 3 THEN 'Mar'
    ->         WHEN p.month_num = 4 THEN 'Apr'
    ->         WHEN p.month_num = 5 THEN 'May'
    ->         WHEN p.month_num = 6 THEN 'Jun'
    ->         WHEN p.month_num = 7 THEN 'Jul'
    ->         WHEN p.month_num = 8 THEN 'Aug'
    ->         WHEN p.month_num = 9 THEN 'Sep'
    ->         WHEN p.month_num = 10 THEN 'Oct'
    ->         WHEN p.month_num = 11 THEN 'Nov'
    ->         WHEN p.month_num = 12 THEN 'Dec'
    ->     END AS 'Timeline',
    ->     p.ck_pos_median AS 'CK+ Median',
    ->     n.ck_neg_median AS 'CK- Median'
    -> FROM
    ->     (SELECT 
    ->         s.median_month_pos AS 'month_num',
    ->             ROUND(AVG(ck_pos), 1) AS 'ck_pos_median'
    ->     FROM
    ->         (SELECT 
    ->         @row_num_pos:=CASE
    ->                 WHEN @median_group_pos = q.month_num THEN @row_num_pos + 1
    ->                 ELSE 1
    ->             END AS 'count_of_group',
    ->             @median_group_pos:=q.month_num AS 'median_month_pos',
    ->             q.month_num,
    ->             q.ck_pos,
    ->             (SELECT 
    ->                     COUNT(*)
    ->                 FROM
    ->                     result_management_report
    ->                 WHERE
    ->                     ck_pos IS NOT NULL
    ->                         AND MONTH(order_date) = q.month_num) AS total_month
    ->     FROM
    ->         (SELECT 
    ->         MONTH(order_date) AS 'month_num', ck_pos
    ->     FROM
    ->         result_management_report
    ->     WHERE
    ->         ck_pos IS NOT NULL
    ->     ORDER BY MONTH(order_date) , ck_pos ASC) AS q) AS s
    ->     WHERE
    ->         s.count_of_group BETWEEN (s.total_month / 2.0) AND (s.total_month / 2.0 + 1)
    ->     GROUP BY s.median_month_pos) AS p
    ->         JOIN
    ->     (SELECT 
    ->         s.median_month_neg AS 'month_num',
    ->             ROUND(AVG(ck_neg), 1) AS 'ck_neg_median'
    ->     FROM
    ->         (SELECT 
    ->         @row_num_neg:=CASE
    ->                 WHEN @median_group_neg = q.month_num THEN @row_num_neg + 1
    ->                 ELSE 1
    ->             END AS 'count_of_group',
    ->             @median_group_neg:=q.month_num AS 'median_month_neg',
    ->             q.month_num,
    ->             q.ck_neg,
    ->             (SELECT 
    ->                     COUNT(*)
    ->                 FROM
    ->                     result_management_report
    ->                 WHERE
    ->                     ck_neg IS NOT NULL
    ->                         AND MONTH(order_date) = q.month_num) AS total_month
    ->     FROM
    ->         (SELECT 
    ->         MONTH(order_date) AS 'month_num', ck_neg
    ->     FROM
    ->         result_management_report
    ->     WHERE
    ->         ck_neg IS NOT NULL
    ->     ORDER BY MONTH(order_date) , ck_neg ASC) AS q) AS s
    ->     WHERE
    ->         s.count_of_group BETWEEN (s.total_month / 2.0) AND (s.total_month / 2.0 + 1)
    ->     GROUP BY s.median_month_neg) AS n ON p.month_num = n.month_num
    -> ORDER BY p.month_num;
+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
| month_num | Timeline | CK+ Median | CK- Median |
+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
|         1 | Jan      |        2.0 |        2.0 |
|         2 | Feb      |        2.0 |        3.0 |
|         3 | Mar      |        2.0 |        3.0 |
|         4 | Apr      |        4.0 |        4.0 |
|         5 | May      |        2.0 |        3.0 |
|         6 | Jun      |        3.0 |        3.0 |
|         7 | Jul      |        4.0 |        4.0 |
|         8 | Aug      |        3.0 |        7.0 |
|         9 | Sep      |        4.0 |       12.0 |
|        10 | Oct      |        5.0 |        8.0 |
|        11 | Nov      |        4.0 |        9.0 |
|        12 | Dec      |        2.0 |       12.0 |
+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
12 rows in set (6.22 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Hi Bernd, I just checked and it works fabulously! I'm gonna try to understand what you did and modify it for other years and data sets but thank you so much!

Comment: @Heeje Cho - thanks for your response. let me know if you want help to understand the query. in my profile is also my email